# Angular 5 web app - slow due to heavy 2-way data binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, performance

My Angular 5 / NodeJS web app is quite slow and takes 5 seconds to load the page as in the screenshot.

All the checkboxes are having 2-way binding.
And there are 176 checkboxes in each tab. The screen is similar in other tabs.
There are 5 tabs and hence 5 * 176 = 704 checkboxes with 2-way data binding.

Is this too much data binding for the Angular app and is heavy 2-way data binding not recommended in Angular apps?

For old AngularJS I found people recommend https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce for heavy data binding. Should I use any such external framework for Angular5?

Switching between tabs also takes a bit longer, even though the data is loaded from memory. The actual function to load the data from memory executes in less than 1 milliseconds. But the UI rendering takes longer.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<p-tabPanel [header]="version.TaxonomyVersionRange" *ngFor="let version of versions; let i = index" [selected]="i == (versions.length - 1)"
    [cache]="true">

    <div>
        <b>{{selectedTable.tableLabel}} - [ Version : {{selectedVersion}} ]</b>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g">
        <!-- Rows -->
        <div class="ui-g-6">
            <p-table [value]="row.Labels" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rows</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.rowlabel}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </div>

        <!-- Columns -->
        <div class="ui-g-6">

            <p-table [value]="column.Labels" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Columns</th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-column>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{column.collabel}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div>
        <b>Table Layout and Cells Selection</b>
    </div>
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <p-dataTable [value]="cellDatas[selectedVersionTabIndex].rows" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="500px" frozenWidth="100px"
            unfrozenWidth="1535px" [loading]="loading" loadingIcon="fa-spinner" *ngIf="renderCells">

            <!-- First column -->
            <p-column [style]="{'width':'100px', 'background-color': 'rgb(235, 237, 240)', 'text-align': 'left'}" frozen="true">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <p-checkbox binary="true" label="All" [(ngModel)]="selectAll" (onChange)="selectAllCells($event)" *ngIf="renderCells"></p-checkbox>
                </ng-template>

                <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                    <p-checkbox binary="true" label={{row.ordrow}} [(ngModel)]="row.rowSelectAll" (onChange)='rowCheckboxSelectEvent(row, $event)'
                        pTooltip='{{row.ordrow}} - {{row.rowlabel}}'></p-checkbox>
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>

            <!-- Reminaing columns-->
            <p-column *ngFor="let col of column.Labels; let i=index" [field]="col" [header]="col.ordcol" [style]="{'width':'75px', 'text-align': 'center'}">
                <!-- Header checkbox -->
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <p-checkbox binary="true" label={{col.ordcol}} [(ngModel)]="columnHeaderCheckboxesSelected[i]" (onChange)='columnCheckboxSelectEvent(col, $event)'
                        pTooltip={{col.collabel}}></p-checkbox>
                </ng-template>

                <!-- Cells checkboxes -->
                <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                    <p-checkbox binary="true" [(ngModel)]="row.columns[i].selected" [disabled]="row.columns[i].disabled" [style]="{'backgroundColor':'grey'}"
                        (onChange)='cellsCheckboxEvent(i)' *ngIf="row.columns[i]"></p-checkbox>
                </ng-template>
            </p-column>

            <p-footer>There are {{cellRows.length}} row(s) and {{column.Labels.length}} column(s). </p-footer>
        </p-dataTable>
    </ng-template>

</p-tabPanel>
```

**JSON**

```
[
[{
        TaxonomyVersionRange: "2.0",
        rows: [{},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "390",
                rowlabel: "other transferable assets that are of high liquidity and credit quality: credit quality step 3",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50223,
                            datapointid: 108464
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50224,
                            datapointid: 108671
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50225,
                            datapointid: 108466
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50226,
                            datapointid: 108673
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "400",
                rowlabel: "ASSETS WHICH MEET THE REQUIREMENTS OF ART. 416 (1) (b) AND (d) BUT DO NOT MEET THE REQUIREMENTS OF ART. 417 (b)AND (c) CRR: assets not controlled by a liquidity management function",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50227,
                            datapointid: 106218
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50228,
                            datapointid: 107664
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50229,
                            datapointid: 106219
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50230,
                            datapointid: 107665
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "410",
                rowlabel: "ASSETS WHICH MEET THE REQUIREMENTS OF ART. 416 (1) (b) AND (d) BUT DO NOT MEET THE REQUIREMENTS OF ART. 417 (b)AND (c) CRR: assets not legally and practically readily available at any time during the next 30 days to be liquidated via outright sale via a simple repurchase agreements on an approved repurchase markets",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50231,
                            datapointid: 106216
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50232,
                            datapointid: 107662
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50233,
                            datapointid: 106217
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50234,
                            datapointid: 107663
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "420",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: Cash",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50235,
                            datapointid: 106223
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50236,
                            datapointid: 107669
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50237,
                            datapointid: 106225
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50238,
                            datapointid: 107671
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "430",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: Central bank exposures, to the extent that these exposures can be drawn down in times of stress",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50239,
                            datapointid: 106097
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50240,
                            datapointid: 107543
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50241,
                            datapointid: 106098
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50242,
                            datapointid: 107544
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "440",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 0% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on sovereigns",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50243,
                            datapointid: 106148
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50244,
                            datapointid: 107594
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50245,
                            datapointid: 106150
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50246,
                            datapointid: 107596
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "450",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 0% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: claims guaranteed by sovereigns",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50247,
                            datapointid: 106209
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50248,
                            datapointid: 107655
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50249,
                            datapointid: 106211
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50250,
                            datapointid: 107657
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "460",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 0% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by central banks",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50251,
                            datapointid: 106143
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50252,
                            datapointid: 107589
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50253,
                            datapointid: 106145
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50254,
                            datapointid: 107591
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "470",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 0% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by non-central government public sector entities, regions with fiscal autonomy to raise and collect taxes and local authorities",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50255,
                            datapointid: 106174
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50256,
                            datapointid: 107620
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50257,
                            datapointid: 106176
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50258,
                            datapointid: 107622
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "480",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 0% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by Bank for International Settlements, the International Monetary Fund, the European Union, the European Financial Stability Facility, the European Stability Mechanism or multilateral development banks",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50259,
                            datapointid: 106159
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50260,
                            datapointid: 107605
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50261,
                            datapointid: 106160
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50262,
                            datapointid: 107606
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "490",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: Transferable securities other than those referred to in 3.3 of the LCR-Assets' template representing claims on or claims guaranteed by sovereigns or central banks issued in domestic currencies by the sovereign or central bank in the currency and country in which the liquidity risk is being taken or issued in foreign currencies, to the extent that holding of such debt matches the liquidity needs of the bank¿s operations in that third country",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50263,
                            datapointid: 106162
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50264,
                            datapointid: 107608
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50265,
                            datapointid: 106163
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50266,
                            datapointid: 107609
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "500",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 20% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on sovereigns",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50267,
                            datapointid: 106149
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50268,
                            datapointid: 107595
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50269,
                            datapointid: 106151
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50270,
                            datapointid: 107597
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "510",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 20% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: claims guaranteed by sovereigns",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50271,
                            datapointid: 106210
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50272,
                            datapointid: 107656
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50273,
                            datapointid: 106212
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50274,
                            datapointid: 107658
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "520",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 20% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by central banks",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50275,
                            datapointid: 106144
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50276,
                            datapointid: 107590
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50277,
                            datapointid: 106146
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50278,
                            datapointid: 107592
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "530",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 20% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by non-central government public sector entities, regions with fiscal autonomy to raise and collect taxes and local authorities",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50279,
                            datapointid: 106175
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50280,
                            datapointid: 107621
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50281,
                            datapointid: 106177
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50282,
                            datapointid: 107623
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "540",
                rowlabel: "transferable securities with a 20% risk weight and not an obligation of an institution or any of its affiliated entities: representing claims on or claims guaranteed by multilateral development banks",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50283,
                            datapointid: 106172
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50284,
                            datapointid: 107618
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50285,
                            datapointid: 106173
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50286,
                            datapointid: 107619
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "550",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: transferable securities other than those referred to in point 3.3 to 3.5 of the LCR-Assets' template that fulfil all the conditions specified in Art. 5 of Annex III CRR",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50287,
                            datapointid: 106165
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50288,
                            datapointid: 107611
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50289,
                            datapointid: 106168
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50290,
                            datapointid: 107614
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "560",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: transferable securities other than those referred to in 3.3 to 3.6 of the LCR-Assets' template that qualify for a 50 % or better risk weight under Chapter 2, Title II of Part Three or are internally rated as having an equivalent credit quality, and do not represent a claim on an SSPE, an institution or any of its affiliated entities",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50291,
                            datapointid: 106166
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50292,
                            datapointid: 107612
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50293,
                            datapointid: 106169
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50294,
                            datapointid: 107615
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "570",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: transferable securities other than those referred to in 3.3 to 3.7 of the LCR-Assets' template that are collateralised by assets that qualify for a 35 % or better risk weight under Chapter 2, Title II of Part Three or are internally rated as having an equivalent credit quality, and are fully and completely secured by mortgages on residential property in accordance with Art. 125 CRR",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50295,
                            datapointid: 106164
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50296,
                            datapointid: 107610
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50297,
                            datapointid: 106167
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50298,
                            datapointid: 107613
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "580",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: standby credit facilities granted by central banks within the scope of monetary policy to the extent that these facilities are not collateralised by liquid assets and excluding emergency liquidity assistance",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50299,
                            datapointid: 106082
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50300,
                            datapointid: 107528
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50301,
                            datapointid: 106083
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50302,
                            datapointid: 107529
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "590",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: Legal or statutory minimum deposits with the central credit institution and other statutory or contractually available liquid funding from the central credit institution or institutions that are members of the network referred to in Art. 113(7) CRR, or eligible for the waiver provided in Art. 10, to the extent that this funding is not collateralised by liquid assets , if the credit institution belongs to a network in accordance with legal or statutory provisions.",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50303,
                            datapointid: 106084
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50304,
                            datapointid: 107530
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50305,
                            datapointid: 106085
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50306,
                            datapointid: 107531
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "600",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: exchange traded, centrally cleared common equity shares, that are a constituent of a major stock index, denominated in the domestic currency of the Member State and not issued by an institution or any of its affiliates",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50307,
                            datapointid: 106205
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50308,
                            datapointid: 107651
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50309,
                            datapointid: 106206
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50310,
                            datapointid: 107652
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                tableid: 281,
                ordrow: "610",
                rowlabel: "ITEMS SUBJECT TO SUPPLEMENTARY REPORTING OF LIQUID ASSETS: gold listed on a recognised exchange, held on an allocated basis",
                columns: [{
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "010",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50311,
                            datapointid: 106224
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "020",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50312,
                            datapointid: 107670
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "030",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50313,
                            datapointid: 106226
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        disabled: false,
                        ordcol: "040",
                        selected: false,
                        datapoints: [{
                            trcid: 50314,
                            datapointid: 107672
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

]

Comment: Does that work faster if you remove the two way data binding?

Comment: Can you try using their selection methods instead? [Docs here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/selection)

Comment: @TheUnreal After removing all the 2-way binding, very marginally better. No big difference. Thx

Comment: @sabithpocker Thx, but we also want to select individual cells seperately. So row selection alone won't be suitable.

Comment: @Jay if there is no big difference why this question title is `slow due to heavy 2-way data binding`? How did you decide it's slow from the 2-way data binding?

Comment: You can check memory, rendering performance in chrome dev tools. You will have to pinpoint what is causing the issue. Anyhow, its not possible to check it with a screenshot. As @Jay pointed out, isolating or removing suspected items can shed some light. Try reducing number of cells, or number of tabs and check if it cause too much difference in performance.

Comment: @sabithpocker  Yes if there is only 1 tab or if the number of cells is very less it makes a big difference and performs better.  If there are more data the cell checkbox selection and tab switching takes more time.

Comment: Can you try implementing the same using reactive form instead of `ngModel`?